# Mobile First Native Android - Adapter not returning any result

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

I am following the documentation given by IBM (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/creating-first-native-android-mobilefirst-application/)

After calling `request.send(new MyInvokeListener());` there is no sucess or failure call back. Receiving an error message "Android Prototype stopped working."

Adapter is working fine when i right click on the adapter --> Run As --> Call Mobile First Adapter

Below is my android native code.

```
public class TaskFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(TaskActivity.this);



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Establishing connection...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                final WLClient client = WLClient.createInstance(TaskActivity.this);
                client.connect(new MyConnectListener());

                URI adapterPath = new URI("/adapters/TaskAdapter/getAllTasks");

                WLResourceRequest request = new WLResourceRequest(adapterPath,WLResourceRequest.GET);


                request.send(new MyInvokeListener());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           // Dialog.setMessage("Loading Tasks..");
           return "test";
        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {



            Dialog.dismiss();

            ArrayList<ListViewModel> result = AssignAndGetCurrentTaskResults();
            tvListCount.setText(GetActionBarString());

            adapter = new ArrayDataAdapter(taContext, R.layout.task_row_item, result);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

My InvokeListner Class

```
public class MyInvokeListener implements WLResponseListener {
        public void onSuccess(WLResponse response) {

            try {
                allTaskResults= ParseData(response.getResponseJSON().getJSONArray("array"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public void onFailure(WLFailResponse response) {

         }
    }
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? You are not printing the response from onFailure, so why would you see the failure? print the response: Log.i("mypoject",Failure: " + response.getErrorMsg());

Comment: Actually, i am putting a break point there to see if it is getting hit or not.

Comment: Doesn't sound related to MFP code.

Comment: Below is the information from logcat                           E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-4
    Process: com.vdot.androidprototype, PID: 21242
    java.lang.Error: java.io.EOFException
            at com.worklight.common.security.WLCertManager.loadKeystore(WLCertManager.java:457)
            at com.worklight.common.security.WLCertManager.getKeyPair(WLCertManager.java:436)
            at com.worklight.common.security.WLOAuthCertManager.getKeyPair(WLOAuthCertManager.java:89)

Comment: Obviously you're doing something in your application then, which you did not mention the question. Elaborate on your application, the scenario, if there's anything special in its setup, if there's any security involved... also try with a fresh app that only does invocation - like in the sample. Is the sample working?

Comment: There is no security involved in application, i just created an android prototype to invoke an adapter. i also tried disabling some of my McAfee features to see if it solves my issue. I am newbie to this mobile development

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial? Did you try the sample application? Is the sample working for you? If you want further help, you need to provide a project that can be used locally and debugged.

Comment: Actually the same prototype had worked before for me and it suddenly stopped working now..

Comment: I will try to create a brand new android application again and see if it works for me or not.

Comment: I tried creating a brand new application and it worked for me. I believe request.send is in async task which also has a call back handler (MyInvokeListner) is causing long running which in turn android is throwing an exception. Taking out that code from async task and doing my logic on call back method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the code which creates and call to mobile first adapter from async task solved my problem.

There is a window leakage in android doing so.